# Touch and drag cancels click on desktop Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, touch

Chrome on iOS allows you to touch a button, move your finger a bit WITHIN the button, release, and  still count the action as a click.

Likewise, Desktop Chrome allows you to mouse down, move within the button, and mouse up, counting as a click.

However, touch events for Chrome on a hybrid tablet device cancels the click as soon as your finger starts to move.

Is there any way to replicate the experience I'm getting on the iOS version and Desktop w/ mouse?

Things I've tried so far:

- various Chrome flags
- putting the device in tablet mode
- touch-action: none & touch-action: manipulation